# DataTable con relaciones laravel 5.8 (mostrar nombre en vez de id)

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, eloquent, controller

buenas, tengo un datatable el cual obtengo los datos por ajax, logro obtener correctamente los datos de mi tabla horario, pero esta me trae el id de profesor y vehiculo, ya que estas son las que estan en la tabla, pero estoy intentando obtener el nombre y apellidos del profesor mediante el id y lo mismo con vehiculo.

Este es mi datatable

```
var clase = "clase";
var fecha = "fecha";
var hora = "hora";
var minutos_bloque = "minutos_bloque";
var id_profesor = "id_profesor";
var id_vehiculo = "id_vehiculo";
var id_alumno_editar = $('#id_alumno').val();

var table3 = $('#horarioPracticoEditar_dt').DataTable({ // Propiedades de la Datatable Principal
  'serverSide'  : true,
  'ajax'        : {
    'url': "{{ route('alumno.editar_horario') }}",
    'data': {"id_alumno": id_alumno_editar},
    'type': "GET"
  },
  'columns'     : [
    {render:
      function ( data, type, row ) {
        return 'Clase '+row[clase];
      }
    },
    {data: fecha},
    {data: hora},
    {data: minutos_bloque},
    {data: id_profesor},
    {data: id_vehiculo},
    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
  ]
});
```

esta es la funcion con la que traigo los datos, lo que esta comentado es como estaba intentando llamar los datos, que segun yo, puedo manipular en jquery para mostrarlo en la datatable (quizas aqui estoy mal)

```
public function editar_horario(Request $request){ // TABLA HORARIO EDITAR
  if ($request->ajax()) {
    $id_alumno = $request->get('id_alumno');
    $horario = horarioModel::latest()->where('id_alumno','=',$id_alumno)->get();
    //$horario->profesor['nombre'];
    //$horario->profesor->apellidos;
    //$horario->vehiculo->marca;
    //$horario->vehiculo->modelo;
    //$horario->vehiculo->patente;
    return datatables::of($horario)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
               // EL ROW DEBE INDICAR EL NOMBRE DE LA ID EN LA TABLA
              $btn = '<div class="btn-group elevation-2">
                           <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_horario.'" data-original-title="Editar" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info editarAlumno"><i class="fas ion-ios-create" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                           <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_horario.'" data-original-title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger eliminarAlumno"><i class="fas ion-md-trash" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                       </div>';
              return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
  }

  return view('Alumno.alumno');
}
```

Esta es la forma en que tengo mis relaciones en el modelo de horario, lo mas probable es que aqui tenga el problema, pero segun yo esta bien, o bien puede ser la forma en que estoy llamando las relaciones en el controlador

```
public function profesor(){
  return $this->belongsTo(profesorModel::class, 'id_profesor', 'id_horario');
}

public function vehiculo(){
  return $this->belongsTo(vehiculoModel::class, 'id_vehiculo', 'id_horario');
}
```

esta es la relacion de profesor

```
public function horario(){
  return $this->hasMany(horarioModel::class, 'id_horario', 'id_profesor');
}
```

y este es el de mi modelo vehiculo

```
public function horario(){
  return $this->hasMany(horarioModel::class, 'id_horario', 'id_vehiculo');
}
```

y para que se entienda mejor, esto es lo que trae mi datatable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las 2 tablas relacionadas de las cuales quieres hacer la consulta para obtener dicho dato?

Comment: quiero traer los datos desde la tabla profesor y vehiculo, con el id que tengo en la tabla horario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***SOLUCIONADO***

Tenia mal mis relaciones respecto a las FK

*Modelo horario*

```
public function profesor(){
  return $this->belongsTo(profesorModel::class, 'id_profesor', 'id_profesor');
}

public function vehiculo(){
  return $this->belongsTo(vehiculoModel::class, 'id_vehiculo', 'id_vehiculo');
}
```

*Modelo profesor*

```
public function horario(){                    //   fk       -     pk
  return $this->hasMany(horarioModel::class, 'id_horario', 'id_horario');
}
```

*Modelo vehículo*

```
public function horario(){                    //   fk       -     pk
  return $this->hasMany(horarioModel::class, 'id_horario', 'id_horario');
}
```

y de esta forma lo envie a mi vista

```
public function editar_horario(Request $request){ // TABLA HORARIO EDITAR
if ($request->ajax()) {
  $id_alumno = $request->get('id_alumno');
  $horario = horarioModel::latest()->where('id_alumno','=',$id_alumno)->get();
  return datatables::of($horario)
          ->addIndexColumn()
          ->addColumn('action', function($row){
             // EL ROW DEBE INDICAR EL NOMBRE DE LA ID EN LA TABLA
            $btn = '<div class="btn-group elevation-2">
                         <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_horario.'" data-original-title="Editar" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info editarAlumno"><i class="fas ion-ios-create" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                         <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_horario.'" data-original-title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger eliminarAlumno"><i class="fas ion-md-trash" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                     </div>';
            return $btn;
          })
          ->addColumn('profesor',function($horario){
            return $horario->profesor->nombre.' '.$horario->profesor->apellidos;
          })
          ->addColumn('vehiculo',function($horario){
            return $horario->vehiculo->marca.' '.$horario->vehiculo->modelo.' '.$horario->vehiculo->patente;
          })
          ->rawColumns(['action', 'profesor', 'vehiculo'])
          ->make(true);
}

return view('Alumno.alumno');
}
```

en mi jquery

```
var table3 = $('#horarioPracticoEditar_dt').DataTable({
  'serverSide'  : true,
  'ajax'        : {
    'url': "{{ route('alumno.editar_horario') }}",
    'data': {"id_alumno": id_alumno_editar},
    'type': "GET"
  },
  'columns'     : [
    {render:
      function ( data, type, row ) {
        return 'Clase '+row[clase];
      }
    },
    {data: fecha},
    {data: hora},
    {data: minutos_bloque},
    {data: 'profesor', name: 'profesor', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    {data: 'vehiculo', name: 'vehiculo', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
  ]
});
```

y este vendría a ser el resultado deseado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]